# Drupal - Multiple Schema

Tags: database, drupal, shared-data

I was tasked to develop a site which has 2 ends; front end and back end. I was instructed to use drupal 7.x. Now, my problem is that, is it possible in drupal to have different ui for "admin.mysite.com" from "mysite.com" which has shared database? The two sites are multisite installed in drupal. Please let me know.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to see the admin side of your Drupal site, a user with the appropriate admin-style permissions will just have to go to **yoursite.com/user/login** to enter in their username and password.  Once they've logged in, they'll be able to see the appropriate admin-level stuff they have permissions to see (such as the content management section, user management section, etc).

You can have any number of admins with different types of permissions who may be able to see all or a sub-section of the admin-pages.

Does that make sense?